# Contents of text file into SQL Server table, using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a number of flat text files whose contents I need to import into an SQL Server table that I have previously created. I am using a SSIS package that utilises an import column task. This works, however, it fails to preserve any line feeds.
Just to clarify, the text on each of the files is meant to be imported into one column/row, so if the text on the file is

```
The cat is big  
and the dog is small
```

the line feed needs to be preserved when imported into SQL Server. At the moment, what I get is:

```
The cat is big and the dog is small
```

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Paths.txt:

C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\DEV_SANDPIT_TEST_RESOURCES\TextFileToTableField\test1.txt
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\DEV_SANDPIT_TEST_RESOURCES\TextFileToTableField\test2.txt
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\DEV_SANDPIT_TEST_RESOURCES\TextFileToTableField\test3.txt
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\DEV_SANDPIT_TEST_RESOURCES\TextFileToTableField\test4.txt

test1.txt

[image: raw file]

data flow:

[image: data flow]

Hope that helps.

Comment: How did you check that the newline is missing? What did you use to query the data? SSMS won't display newlines. How did you *import* the data? Newline means new row, and obviously this isn't two rows

Comment: If it's a flat-file, how are you storing line breaks?   Are you sure it's not just some wrapping in e.g. excel when you view the file?   Could you edit your question to include a sample of the raw input data please.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I copied and pasted the text from the table on to Notepad ++, no carriage returns.

Comment: @JeffUK:  Docs to import were created by myself (for testing purposes) using Notepad++. I can see the {CR}{LF} symbols.

Comment: @JeffUK: Please see edits showing, my driver file paths.txt ,which works fine, one of the test files (test1.txt) which do get imported (without carriage returns)  and a screen shot of the data flow.

Comment: What would you want the resultant table in the database to look like, do you want one row for the entire raw file, for instance?

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the flat file connection manager settings?

Comment: @JeffUK: I am already getting on row holding the contents of each text file.  What I am missing is the the carriage returns. They seem to be dropped during the process.

Comment: @Hadi:  I believe the flat file connection manager refers to my 'driver' file, paths.txt only - I stand to be corrected. This file is treated fine. My issue is with the actual targets for the transfer. I don't see a way to fine tune how they get imported.

Answer (score 0):

By default SSIS row delimiter is set to {CR}{LF}. If the text file are generated on a unix-like system then the line delimiter is only {LF}. This could be one reason why you don't see two lines when importing, so if you are not able to see what the actual delimiter is (notepad++ will do) then just test by changing the header and row delimiters in SSIS connection manager to {LF}.

Comment: I created the text files myself, for testing purposes, using Notepad++. I can see the delimiters being {CR}{LF}. Environment is Windows.